# How do I place an image next to a title in a navigation bar controller?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I think the first step would be to add an image view.  If I have to add any code, please tell me where it belongs.  I'm not asking you to go out of your way to tell me how to add the code.  I know how to do that.  I just want to know where in "UIViewController.h" the code belongs. Oh, and if the image has to be a PNG, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code would put an image where the title goes.  If you want both, you'll need a UIView that has both the image and a label for title added to it, and then set that UIView as the view in the second line of code below (NOTE:  If using ARC remove the autorelease part):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];
```

Comment: If you wanted a title and image you would do something like UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:<your frame>];  Then add the imageView and label to that UIView:  [containerView addSubview: myImageView];  and [containerView addSubview: myLabelView];, then set the containerView as done in second line above...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it seems like there should be a better way to do this.  I'm going to see what Oleg has to say about it.  I'll give you a rep if I can't find a better answer.

Comment: This is the best way to do it, but I welcome your research.  It is far better (BTW) than simply adding a subview as Oleg said.  There could be unintended results.  You should use the titleView as I've said.  That's what it is there for.

Comment: I thought you were telling me to go through the pain of dragging a UIView into my storyboard.  That is why I wanted to wait for a better solution.  I now see I was wrong.

Comment: Okay, care to tell me how to put the code in?  I thought I knew where, but I don't.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code into your `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"logo_icon.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(yourXposition, yourYposition, yourWidth, yourHeight);
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: What view are we talking about?  The content view?

Comment: You can add any subview to your UINavigationBar. In my example I've created UIImageView and init it with an image I want to add

Comment: The challenge with using this technique is knowing what x position to use. You can't just calculate the with of the title as a string with a specific font, as it might be truncated by the navigation bar.